# Camera Input: Unsupported Parameter

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder

Firstly, please forgive it is already asked one or can be find easily with Google. I am posting this since I do have only limited time. Here is code to record audio and video.

```
        stopPreview();

        Log.d("streamer", "Start camera.....");
        videoRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        videoRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceView.getHolder()
                .getSurface());
        videoRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        videoRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        videoRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
        videoRecorder.setVideoSize(800, 600);
        videoRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        videoRecorder.setOutputFile(videoPipe.getOutput());
        videoRecorder.prepare();
        videoRecorder.start();
        Log.d("streamer", "Start camera.....action.......");

        Log.d("streamer", "Start mic.....");
        audioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        audioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        audioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.RAW_AMR);
        audioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        audioRecorder.setOutputFile(audioPipe.getOutput());
        audioRecorder.prepare();
        audioRecorder.start();
        Log.d("streamer", "Start mic.....action");
```

But, when I run it, the above code produces the following on logcat.

```
12-22 09:05:43.456: E/CameraInput(2407): Unsupported parameter(x-pvmf/media-input-node/cap-config-interface;valtype=key_specific_value)
12-22 09:05:43.456: E/CameraInput(2407): VerifiyAndSetParameter failed on parameter #0

.....
12-22 09:05:43.456: E/CameraInput(2407): VerifiyAndSetParameter failed on parameter #0
12-22 09:05:43.464: E/MediaProfiles(2407): mCodec : 2
12-22 09:05:43.464: E/MediaProfiles(2407): mCodec : 1
12-22 09:05:43.464: E/MediaProfiles(2407): mCodec : 3
```

And, the surface view showing preview seems to be freezed. It shows last taken frame of image. Also, the video & audio doesn't seems to be recording. What will be the problem? Any help is very much appreciated!

NOTE:

I am trying this on Samsung Galaxy Tab with Android 2.2.

Commenting the following two lines also doesn't seems to solve the problem

```
        videoRecorder.setVideoSize(800, 600);
        videoRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
```

The following permissions are set on the manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see the [Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html), for MPEG-4 SP, you need to use 3GP (`THREE_GPP`) output format.
So you can try with

```
videoRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
```

Comment: I want to record this media for live streaming with live555, and i need mpeg-4, what am I do?

Comment: You want the file format to be MP4 or video codec to be MPEG-4 SP ? These are 2 seperate things. 3GP File format is same as MP4 file format with some changes to some atoms. So a MP4 player should support 3GP as well. Pls check.

Comment: If you still want your File Format to be MPEG-4, then you have to change your video codec to H.263 or H.264 AVC. BTW, H.263 is same as MPEG-4 SP, so you can use H.263 video codec with MPEG-4 file format combination for your requirement.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I was on the way to office. Can I have an elementary stream file with mediarecorder. ie., `m4e` - (MPEG-4 Video) or `264` - (H.264 Video). Or can I output an `mpg` - (MPEG-1 or 2 Program Stream)(audio + video)?

Comment: yes, you can have only video content (mpeg4 video or h.264 video) in a MP4 file with media recorder. In this case you would set on `setVideoEncoder()` and other video related apis. If you want both audio + video, you can use mpg as output format. In this case you need to set audio and video parameters on the same MediaRecorder instance.

Comment: Would you please let me know how to do that? I think that will work for me(but I am not sure). Video content only with an mp4 file.

Comment: You have already done that. your `videoRecorder` would create MP4 file with only video content. We can further discussions in Chat.

Comment: Sorry! But how do I get into chat? Which chatroom I want to join? It is my first attempt. Shows 'an error occured' on clicking 'automatically move this discussion to chat'.